# Updating an element via ajax: shall I use global variable to keep element's id or it is a bad habit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a page I have a list of dates which I want to edit via AJAX.

Example:

```
<li>January 2015<a data-update_url="/frame_date/22/update/" class="update" id="update_framedate_22" href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
```

When the user clicks on the Edit link, I catch element id and the edit link.

Than AJAX requests the update form from the server. And now I have to place the form instead of the element with the mentioned id.

In other words, in frame_date_update_show_get I need element's id. In the example below, I keep it in the global variable date_id. But inside me there is a protest: I was always taught that global variables is a bad practice. But in this case I don't know how to get along without the global variable date_id.

Could you give me some piece of advice: is my code acceptable or there is a better way to cope with the problem.

```
function frame_date_update_show_get(data){
    $("#" + date_id).replaceWith(data);
}

function frame_date_update_get_data(){
    date_id = this.getAttribute('id')
    var cuaghtUrl = this.getAttribute('data-update_url');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: cuaghtUrl,
        success: frame_date_update_show_get,
        error: fail
    });
}

var date_id = ""
```

Comment: A suggestion: use [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) instead (assign ID to it), no need for forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function as success callback function and then call `frame_date_update_show_get` with an additional `date_id` parameter:

```js
function frame_date_update_show_get(data, date_id) {
  $("#" + date_id).replaceWith(data);
}

function frame_date_update_get_data() {
  var date_id = this.getAttribute('id')
  var cuaghtUrl = this.getAttribute('data-update_url');

  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: cuaghtUrl,
    success: function(data) {
      frame_date_update_show_get(data, date_id);
    },
    error: fail
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) combined with AJAX this way:

```js
function dateChange(options){
    switch( options.action ) {
        case 'update':
         if( options.id && options.text && options.updateUrl ) {
             $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: options.updateUrl,
                    data: {
                        id: options.id,
                        html: options.text
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        options.element.html( response );
                        options.element.removeClass('editing');
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log( 'request failed: ' + err.text );
                    }
                });
            };
            break;
        default:
         console.log( 'action invalid' );
            return false;
            break;
    };
};
var editTimeout = null;
$('li[data-update-url]').on('input', function(e) {
    var thisText = $(this);
    thisText.addClass('editing');
    clearTimeout( editTimeout );
    editTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     var updateUrl = thisText.data('updateUrl');
        var id = thisText.data('id');
        dateChange({
            'action': 'update',
            'element': thisText,
            'id': id,
            'updateUrl': updateUrl,
            'text': thisText.html()
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.editing {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li data-update-url="/echo/html/" data-id="update_framedate_22" contenteditable>January 2015</li>
</ul>
```

Check how it works on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kdvfawy/)**.

This code would be easy to expand for other actions you may need, as `delete`, `add`.